# Is offline authentication possible with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-acs, sql-azure-federations

I am currently using Auth0 for the offline authentication with downloading the token and validating the user against it. I am now looking to migrate to the Azure Active Directory - just want to double check if they have anything to support my existing process.

Answer (score 0):

How long do you remain offline? Access tokens in Azure AD have a validity time of one hour and are automatically cached. Technically you could relax the expiration check if you want them to last longer, although that's usually not recommended.

Comment: Offline for not more than a day. So it's actually possible to download the token and with extended expiration period and validate it against that. Right ?

Comment: It is technically possible but there are various caveats. First, the cache in the client libraries will automatically try to renew the token as the expiration time approaches - hence you have to save tokens in your own store. Second, you'll be able to send those tokens only to endpoints you own, as you'll need to customize the expiration validation logic to be more tolerant. If you'd send such a token to say Office365 or Azure API, they would reject it as expired. We are working on making the validity window configurable but we dont have it yet - that will be the proper solution.